# Magento Paypal Order review

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

I'm working on a website that has Paypal Express Checkout integration.  We've disable the ability to checkout from product pages, or the basket page, so it's essentially just another payment option at checkout.

Currently, when a customer selects Paypal, they are immediately redirected to PayPal.  Whilst this has the ability to have an order review step (after the customer enters their details), we would like to change this so that the checkout order review step (6) displays, and the customer would hit "pay now" and then be directed to PayPal from there instead.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour described by you is controlled by two functions on the payment method model, that get called by `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction`/`Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder`.

`Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction` will call the payment method instances `getCheckoutRedirectUrl` and redirect to the given url after saving the payment informations from the checkout (e.g. `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express::getCheckoutRedirectUrl`).

`Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder` is executed on order placement and after saving the order it will redirect to the url given by the payment method instances `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` (e.g. `Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard::getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl`).

So your solution would be to override the Paypal Express payment model, ensure that *getCheckoutRedirectUrl* returns nothing and return the url in *getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl*.

A word of warning though: I'm not that sure how exactly Paypal handles the whole authorisation and capturing of the order, so you might run into problems:
`Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder` will place the order and authorize/capture the orders payment depending on the payment methods configuration. I would assume, that the initial redirect to Paypal authorizes the order on Paypal side and will capture it on order placement. So the payment might fail, because the authorization is missing.